# Can we create a mixed node hyperledger fabric network?

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

1 peer on bluemix enterprise and 1 on azure or even someone's local docker environment? Any weblinks or official documentation are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible (not the default) to create such topology, provided that the Docker container and your other servers can communicate properly (that's a networking problem rather than a Hyperledger one). Follow the official Hyperledger documentation on building your first network (you may have to look *into* the scripts to find out where to change the hosts) and replace the host names accordingly: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/build_network.html. You probably need to configure the firewall and Docker networking.

Comment: well, THEORETICALLY, you can do this. However, while there is technical capacity for this sort of configuration, it does require some degree of cooperation on the networking side of things. e.g. the Orderer service will need to be exposed to the peer running on another cloud provider.